# Higher order derivative and extrema, theorem.

Tags: derivatives, extreme-value-theorem

I wanted ask, maybe someone here can give a site or other source as to where could I find a theorem about higher order derivatives. The conclusion of theorem is as follows: If $f'(x_0)=f''(x_0)=f'''(x_0)=...=f^{(n-1)}(x_0)$ and $f^{n}(x_0)\neq0$ then if $n\neq2k, \,$where $ k\in N$, $x_0$ is not local extrema. If $n=2k$ and $f^{(n)}(x_0)\ge 0$ then $x_0$ is local minimum, if $f^{(n)}(x_0)\le0$ then $x_0$ is local maximum. So there must be a theorem that proves this result, where can I find it?

Comment: I know for sure that Michael Spivak's book titled Calculus has a proof. It is in Chapter 20, Theorem 2.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure where else the proof is (because I didn't really search too much for it). Also, for the theorem to be true, I'm pretty sure you need strict inequalities, not weak ones.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder